# What's the equivalent of Angular's directive link function in an emberjs component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ember.js

In Angular when you create a directive, which is analogous to an Ember component, there's something called the link function where you do all your DOM transformations on the element after it is rendered.

What is the equivalent of that function in Ember?

It doesn't seem to be the `didInsertElement` event because Ember gave a console warning that doing DOM transformation there hurts performance. Is there another event/function that is the idiomatic place in manipulate the component with javascript?

Comment: What sort of DOM manipulation were you planning on doing? Is it something that could be in your template with properties? You could put actions in your markup and handle the actions in your component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's telling you to defer manipulating the DOM. You can do this:

```
didInsertElement(){
  Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, 'doMyThing');
},
doMyThing(){
  console.log("I get run once");
}
```